# How to connect a checker to an arbitrarily instance?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Say I have a checker that reaches into $root.i_dut and inspects some signals there.  A trivial example:

```
module CheckOverflow(input logic clk);
  assert property (@(posedge clk) $root.i_dut.overflow == 1'b0);
endmodule
```

What if I want to use this checker in a test bench where the thing I want to check isn't necessarily instantiated as "$root.i_dut"?  Is there a way to, say, pass a reference to an instance to an instantiated checker?

It seems that UVM solves this problem, using interfaces.  I'm interested in knowing if there's a way to do this just using references, rather than interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can use in this case is a `bind`. This makes it possible to instantiate your checker anywhere inside the hierarchy.

First you need to make the overflow signal an input instead of relying on the hierarchical path:

```
module CheckOverflow(input bit clk, input logic overflow);
```

In your top level testbench you'd add:

```
bind dut_module_name CheckOverflow assertions(
  .clk(<name of the clock signal in the DUT>),
  .overflow(overflow)
);
```

This will cause the checker to be instantiated under the DUT module with the name *assertions* and connect to the specified DUT signals without having to modify the DUT code.

You can find a working example on [EDAPlayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Sz6).

Comment: I'll try it, though the syntax looks backwards compared to the examples in SystemVerilog LRM 3.1a section 17.15 (which is pretty thin).  Any pointers on better documentation describing correct use of 'bind'?

Comment: @JonathanMayer It might be wrong, I don't know it by heart and I didn't open the LRM. Feel free to correct it after you make it work. I usually look up stuff like this on Google and I end up with sites like asicworld.com or testbench.in